# A word loved by poets

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry

> A word loved by poets in five equal parts
>
> The end of a dog is how two of them start
>
> The third can be found in the land of Jafar
>
> The fourth can be useful to learn where you are
>
> The fifth is a word that an anchor might use
>
> Announcing the start of tonight's evening news

Note: A complete answer should explain all of the clues.

Edit: I just noticed that I made a slight error in how this is spelled, in that one of the parts is slightly larger than the other 4.  I'm not sure if I can explain this in the verse and still make it rhyme, so I'm just gonna leave this here.

Hint:

> Just double one of the letters.  It does not affect the pronunciation.

It's been a little while, so here's another hint:

> Note that "dog" and "anchor" are singular.  This is significant.  In retrospect "poets" should probably be singular be as well.

Comment: Following on from your second hint, could you say whether the answer depends on knowledge of the wording used by one specific news anchor, for example from a specific broadcaster?

Comment: @MichaelMaggs Yes, you could definitely say that.  In fact, all of the clues are very specific.  (But don't worry, you don't have to have lived in a specific place to have heard of any of them.)

Comment: I could almost make rot13(Wnoorejbpxl svg, vs gur Arjf napube cneg pbhyq or *xl* sebz *Fxl* Arjf).

Comment: @MichaelMaggs That's not it, though I'm curious how you got to that.  The word does share one thing in common with that guess in that rot13(vg jnf vairagrq ol n cbrg, naq abg bsgra frra ryfrjurer).

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer -- I'm still working on it.

**A word loved by poets in five equal parts**

> I'm not exactly sure what this is saying. Is it 5 words or 5 letters or 5 syllables?

**The end of a dog is how two of them start**

> The end of a dog could be a tail or you could stretch it to mean a paw

**The third can be found in the land of Jafar**

> This is a reference to Aladdin (I'm pretty sure). I'm guessing a genie, lamp, magic carpet or something else

**The fourth can be useful to learn where you are**

> A map or compass or maybe stars

**The fifth is a word that an anchor might use**

**Announcing the start of tonight's evening news**

> Typically they start the news with "good evening" or "Hello"

Comment: You're on the right track on clue 3, but not quite there yet.  Pay attention to the wordplay tag, and think a bit more specifically on the others.  The first clue does indeed refer to letters, but there are more than 5.  (Note the edit to original question - they're not quite equal, my bad.)